# get all the env variable in powershell

Tags: arrays, bash, powershell, arguments

I want to convert the below code from **bash** to **PowerShell** but I am not sure how I can get list of variable. would you mind help me? this code will find all the variable in shell with prefix of conf__ and then add them as parameters.

```
 params=(
    --master "$MASTER"
  )

 for var_name in "${!conf__@}"; 
 do 
       key=${var_name#conf__}; 
       key=${key//_/.}; 
       value=${!var_name}; 
       params+=( --conf "$key=$value" ); 
 done
 echo "myexecutable" "${params[@]}"
```

so far I could convert this:

```
$params = @(
    '--master "$MASTER"'
)

ForEach-Object gci env: | where name -like 'Pro*' {
# but how handle this part?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# Create two-element array.
# Note: 
#  * 'MASTER' is assumed to be the name of an *environment* variable too.
$params = '--master', $env:MASTER

# Append to the array.
$params += 
  Get-Item Env:conf__* | # All env. vars. prefixed with "conf__"
  ForEach-Object {       # Process each
    '--conf'             # Verbatim new array element.
    # Calculated new array element:
    # Construct a "<key>=<value>" string for the env var. at hand.
    # To construct the key, strip the "conf__" prefix and replace any 
    # "_" chars. with "."
    '{0}={1}' -f ($_.Name -replace '^conf__' -replace '_', '.'), $_.Value
  }
```

To pass the resulting array *as individual arguments* to an external program, say `foo`, pass it *as-is*:

```bash
foo $params
```

Note: You may also use `@params`, i.e. use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), though for *external programs* `$params` works too.